# How can I fix my keyboard on linux?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, hardware

I just got a new keyboard (AJAZZ Chinese Brand). It is working fine expect that the <kbd>NUM LOCK</kbd>, <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> and <kbd>Lock</kbd> buttons are not functioning, the LED doesn't respond too. I also have a problem with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Any key as it gives me letters in UPPERCASE instead of for example <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selecting all, it types "A". How can I fix this?

Comment: I found this but on the layout it shows that I have pressed Shift when I press Ctrl, Alt or Windows Key. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and the keyboard is working perfectly on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Change your keyboard setting.
Search for Keyboard in unity dash 
and open **keyboard preferences**

[image]

You can select a country and then choose an language and keyboard variant.  Note that some countries, such as the United States, may show several languages.  Once you’ve made your selection, you can preview it on the sample keyboard displayed below the menu.

[image]

Alternately, on the second tab, select a language and then choose a variant.  Click Add when you’ve made your selection.

[image]

Comment: I found this but on the layout it shows that I have pressed Shift when I press Ctrl, Alt or Windows Key. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and the keyboard is working perfectly on Windows.